# All packages showing inside the virtual environment

Tags: python, pip, package, virtual-environment

Whenever I'm trying `pip/pip3 freeze/list` inside a [venv](https://docs.python.org/3/library/venv.html), it's showing a huge list and I'm guessing it's all the packages available in my machine.
I'm using Python 3.10.12 and pip version is 23.3.1. I tried `--local` but it's showing the same.

I tried all Stack Overflow methods, but they did not work for me. So think I'll get something new.

How can I get the local packages list now?

Comment: So... what is your question?

Comment: How can I the list of get venv packages only

Comment: That's what `pip freeze` does. Without more information, all we can tell is that either you are doing something you are not telling us, or your expectations are unrealistic. If you can [edit] this into an actual well-defined question, we can try to answer. See also the [help] and in particular [How to ask](/help/how-to-ask) as well as the guidance for providing a [mre].

Comment: https://snarky.ca/why-you-should-use-python-m-pip/

Answer (score 0):

Try activating the venv first and then issuing `pip list`.
I just tried it and it lists just the packages installed in the venv and not the global ones.